# Embedded flash video: works locally, but not on staging server

Tags: .net, asp.net, flash

I was able to embed a video that auto plays on my local machine.

When I upload my solution onto my staging server I get nothing. It's weird, everything is the same in the code.

I am running Vista on my local machine and Windows Server 2003 on my server.

Does someone with a little more experience in this feel like pointing me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set the Mime-Type for SWF and FLV files on your server. Check these documents on Adobe's site:

SWF must have a Mime-Type of "application/x-shockwave-flash"

[SWF Mime-Type](http://kb.adobe.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=tn_4151)

FLV must have a Mime-Type of "flv-application/octet-stream"

[FLV Mime-Type](http://kb.adobe.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=tn_19439&sliceId=2)

Answer (score 1):

DGarcia's right -- you'll have to set these manually on IIS.  I just checked my settings and they're just as he specified.  In IIS, right-click and select Properties off your main server node, then click MIME Types.  Should be pretty self-explanatory from there on out.